# To click on an element which contains class and title in selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I want to click on an element which contains class and title in selenium python.

A webpage contains certain folders with unique name. I want to click on a folder by specifying its name or title. Below is the html tag. I tried many ways but I am ending up with errors.

```
<div class="folder">
<p>
<a alt="ABC" title="ABC">ABC</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Initially, it used to work with below :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='ABC']").click()
```

But now it says unable to locate element. Please help me to solve this.

Error:

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does the find_element_by_xpath raise an exception or do you get a wrong element?

Comment: And, you keep mixing up "alt" and "title". So, which attribute are you wanting to use?

Comment: I want to use title. Please help me with this.

Comment: I get "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element" error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the OPs xpath selection is correct in order to find an element by title. To me, an error of "NoSuchElementException" occurs because the element is not in the DOM, not displayed, not clickable, etc before Selenium tries to interact with it.

The common solution here is to wait for the page to load or wait for element to be displayed. While I have not coded in python, a quick search led me to the following.

An example of this can be found [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.Xpath, "//a[@title='ABC']")))
```

This link also lists other wait conditions.

- title_is
- title_contains
- presence_of_element_located
- visibility_of_element_located
- visibility_of
- presence_of_all_elements_located
- text_to_be_present_in_element
- text_to_be_present_in_element_value
- frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
- invisibility_of_element_located
- element_to_be_clickable
- staleness_of
- element_to_be_selected
- element_located_to_be_selected
- element_selection_state_to_be
- element_located_selection_state_to_be
- alert_is_present